# Site templates removed from solution gallery but still appearing in "new site" dialog

Tags: 2010, site-template, sharepoint-server

A client deleted some site templates (WSPs) from the solution gallery. I'm not sure if they were deactivated before they were deleted. They seem to have been also manually deleted from the recycle bin.

But f I click "New Site" in the Site Actions menu, the templates are still available. How can I get them to disappear from the "New Site" dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens when you remove the wsp before disabling the feature!

you need to re-add the exact wsp's(correct version) disable them(feature) and then remove wsp in correct order(retract and then remove)!

if its not the same wsp and you add it back than it will only create two feature which you do not want, iv done it before but it does remove the feature from the list but its still in the hive files and db!

Comment: What if the wsp has been deleted from the recycle bin?